# Windows 7 Slow Searching

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to speed up Windows 7 search?](https://superuser.com/questions/47177/how-to-speed-up-windows-7-search)

I have a new **Windows 7** machine with twice as much RAM and a faster processor than my old Windows Server 2008 R2 Machine.

I am disappointed that searching amongst my 10,000 image files takes twice as long on my new Windows 7 machine.

Both machines have their own copy of these same files.  In other respects e.g. opening my huge Outlook files, the new machine is faster.

The Windows Search Service has started.  And I set indexing on the image folder about 3 days ago.

Any ideas why I suffer from this poor index/search experience?

Other than adding / removing folders, is there anything I can do to tweak indexing?

Answer (score 0):

See this article

http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Folder-to-the-Windows-7-File-Index'

Or go to Control Panel (icon view) > Indexing Options

.

Another article

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistadesktopui/thread/76970267-4121-417d-95af-caf307d6a678

Force an index
http://www.sevenforums.com/gadgets/87399-solved-force-windows-search-indexing.html

.