# Windows Quick Search Extremely Slow

Tags: windows-7, windows, search, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to speed up Windows 7 search?](https://superuser.com/questions/47177/how-to-speed-up-windows-7-search)

My windows 7 computer has been very sluggish lately and one of the main areas I've noticed is the quick search (windows key type what you want press enter).  I have been playing with the indexing and that doesn't seem to be the problem.  Have searched online with very little luck.

Does anyone know how I can speed this up/fix it?  Windows + r seems to be speedy still, but other than that I can't really give much more insight to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Declining search performance can have numerous reasons (e. g., an increasing number of files).

The [Everything search engine](http://www.voidtools.com/) is magnitudes faster than the built-in search.

Speed aside, it has a few additional features that useful (e. g., support for regular expressions).

Comment: Everything seems very good.